EROR: As per Indian regulations, export transactions require a customer name and address
I'm trying to pay Stripe for my project; I have a Stripe developer account and have previously sent the publishable key and secret key. The payment method is redirected to a payment page where I have passed the country region, email, credit detail, name, and CVV, but I'm getting this error. Export transactions in India require the customer's name and address.
get this type of eror:
As per Indian regulations, export transactions require a customer name and address. More info here: https://stripe.com/docs/india-exports stakeoverflow in .net framework
I researchd Stripe payment documentation, but I didn't find an answer.

Your question is lacking a lot of detail. Please can you share the code you're using to integrate/accept payments with Stripe?

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
